# Get city weather and notify an endpoint

Tags: clojure

I'd like some help to improve this cli program. It queries a city's weather and pushes a weather report.

It takes two arguments: the city to query and the apikey for OpenWeatherMap. For example `lein run glasgow abcde12345`.

How to make it more idiomatic clojure? How can I avoid having to pass the apikey multiple times?

````clj
(ns sunshine.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clj-http.client :as http])
  (:require [clojure.data.json :as json])
)


(defn _get
  [url]
  (http/get url)
)


(defn _post
  [url payload]
  (http/post url payload)
)


(defn as_json
  [text]
  (json/read-str text :key-fn keyword)
)


(defn query_weather
  [apikey coords]
  (as_json
   (:body (_get (str "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" (:lat coords) "&lon=" (:lon coords) "&appid=" apikey "&units=metric")))
   )
)


(defn get_city_coords
  [apikey city]
  (let [{:keys [lon lat]} (first (as_json
   (:body (_get (str "http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=" city "&appid=" apikey)))
   ))]
    {:lon lon :lat lat})
  )


(defn unpack
  [raw_message]
  {:desc (:description (first (:weather raw_message))) :temperature (:temp (:main raw_message))})


 (defn get_weather
   [apikey coords]
   (unpack (query_weather apikey coords) )
 )


(defn as_weather_report
  [city weather]
  (str "Current weather in " city ": " (:temperature weather) "ºC with " (:desc weather))
)


(defn notify
  [message]
  (if (:deleted (as_json (:body (_post, "https://api.keen.io/dev/null" {:message message}))))
    (println message)
  )
)


(defn -main
  "Query weather and notify"
  [& args]
  (let [city (first args) apikey (second args)]
    (notify (as_weather_report city (get_weather apikey (get_city_coords apikey city))))
    )
)

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general things:

- ending parentheses belong to the same line
- use a single empty line between definitions
- Clojure uses kebab-case (so `as_json` should be `as-json`, `query_weather` becomes `query-weather` and so on), this applies to names of arguments as well

[`ns`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns) declaration:

- `:gen-class` should be the last reference (order of references is: (:refer-clojure ...) (:require ...) (:use ...) (:import ...) (:load ...) (:gen-class))
- you don't have to use `:require` twice, just use two (or more) vectors inside one `:require`

```
(ns sunshine.core
  (:require [clj-http.client :as http]
            [clojure.data.json :as json])
  (:gen-class))
```

Next three functions (Clojure usually doesn't use underscores, so I just renamed them and used kebab-case)

```
(defn url-get
  [url]
  (http/get url))

(defn url-post
  [url payload]
  (http/post url payload))

(defn as-json
  [text]
  (json/read-str text :key-fn keyword))
```

`query-weather`: you can use [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) here, as well as [`->`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E) (thread-first macro) to increase readability

```
(defn query-weather
  [apikey {:keys [lat lon]}]
  (-> (str "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" lat "&lon=" lon "&appid=" apikey "&units=metric")
      url-get
      :body
      as-json))
```

`get-city-coords`: again, you can use `->` (thread-first macro). When you compare this function with the previous one, you can note the same sequence of `str`, `url-get`, `:body`, `as-json`- maybe you can also avoid this repetition somehow

```
(defn get-city-coords
  [apikey city]
  (let [{:keys [lon lat]} (-> (str "http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=" city "&appid=" apikey)
                              url-get
                              :body
                              as-json
                              first)]
    {:lon lon :lat lat}))
```

`unpack`: you can destructure again

```
(defn unpack
  [{:keys [main weather]}]
  {:desc (:description (first weather))
   :temperature (:temp main)})
```

`get-weather`: without change

```
(defn get-weather
  [apikey coords]
  (unpack (query-weather apikey coords)))
```

`as-weather-report`: destructure

```
(defn as-weather-report
  [city {:keys [temperature desc]}]
  (str "Current weather in " city ": " temperature "°C with " desc))
```

`notify`: `if` with only one branch is [`when`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when), and you can use `->` again

```
(defn notify
  [message]
  (when (-> (url-post "https://api.keen.io/dev/null" {:message message})
            :body
            as-json
            :deleted)
    (println message)))
```

`-main`: destructure, and this time, you can use [`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) (thread-last) macro

```
(defn -main
  "Query weather and notify"
  [& [city apikey]]
  (->> (get-city-coords apikey city)
       (get-weather apikey)
       (as-weather-report city)
       notify))
```

Comment: That is awesome! thank you for the thorough review. One question: is it possible or desirable to curry the functions that require the `apikey`? Would it make easier to read the `main` function because it would use thread-first instead of thread-last?

Comment: Another related question is, if i had to create a http conection session, how would i used it over the lifetime of the program? Whould I have to curry the `get` and `post` functions? What would that look like?